# What Python type annotation to represent generic type class

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

In my Python 3.7.4 code I have the following function.

```
def is_dict(klass: ???) -> bool:
    return klass.__origin__ == dict
```

I'm struggling to get the type annotation right for the `klass` parameter. It's not `type`, for that mypy complains.

> error: "`type`" has no attribute "`__origin__`"

I'm at a loss. What is the correct annotation and is there any **good** documentation about it?

Here's an example of how this function is used:

```
>>> is_dict(typing.Dict[str, int])
True
>>> is_dict(typing.List[str])
False
```

Comment: You probably want `typing.Type[ClassThatHasOrigin]`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type

Comment: That would make it `Type[_AnnotatedAlias]` (see https://github.com/python/typing/blob/master/typing_extensions/src_py3/typing_extensions.py#L1662) but that doesn't make mypy happy: `error: Module 'typing_extensions' has no attribute '_AnnotatedAlias'`

Comment: and using `Annotated` rather than `_AnnotatedAlias` appears to make no difference @AlexHall

Comment: I agree with Alex, you need a class with __origin__ attribute, which class are you referring to here?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use something like `GenericMeta` as suggested in the comments, or try experimenting with creating a custom [protocol](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html) that defines the appropriate `__origin__` attribute, you'll first need to update the type hints for the typing module in [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/typing.pyi) to define these attributes.

However, for now, I recommend using just `Type[Any]` or `Type[object]`.

```py
from typing import Type, Any

# If you want to make minimal modifications to your code, make
# 'klass' dynamically typed.
def is_dict_1(klass: Type[Any]) -> bool:
    return klass.__origin__ == dict

# If you want to make your code robust, assume nothing about 'klass'
# except that it's some sort of type and verify the attribute you're
# about to use exists.
def is_dict_2(klass: Type[object]) -> bool:
    return getattr(klass, '__origin__', None) == dict
```

If you're specifically trying to directly manipulate type hint expressions because you're trying to create some kind of serialization/deserialization library, you could also try taking a look at the source code of libraries like [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) for inspiration.

A little more broadly, I'd also recommend you explore the possibility of minimizing places in your code where you manipulate type hint expressions as runtime entities if possible. The Python typing ecosystem was largely designed to keep the static and runtime worlds separate, so mechanisms for intermingling the two worlds aren't really that convenient to use and aren't always backwards compatible. The typing library internals have changed several times since it was first released in Python 3.5, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the answer:

```
import typing

def is_dict(klass: typing.GenericMeta) -> bool:
    return klass.__origin__ == typing.Dict

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(is_dict(typing.Dict[str, int]))
    print(is_dict(typing.List[str]))
```

Alternatively:

```
def is_dict(klass: typing.GenericMeta) -> bool:
        return klass.__orig_bases__[0] == dict
```

Comment: Thanks, although that's not quite what I was after. I added an example to the original post that hopefully better illustrates what I'm after.

Comment: I think this should give a base for what you need.

Comment: If you wish to only use `dict` or inbuilts, you can refer second example

Comment: That still makes mypy whinge `error: "GenericMeta" has no attribute "__origin__"`

Comment: Notice that my code works and I don't want to change it. I'm only asking about the right annotation for the parameter

Comment: I dont think it's possible to give just a generic class there, you can use: `Type[Union[BaseUser, ProUser]]`

Comment: Basically list all classes you'll send to function, refer: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type

Comment: That's not feasible as the list is unknown and open-ended, but thanks anyway

Comment: Python 3.7+ doesn't have `typing.GenericMeta`.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you should use `cls: type` in this case, because it will accept types like `str` or `int`, but also `typing.Dict`, `typing.List`, etc. from a type level perspective.

You can easily get around mypy's complaint *"type" has no attribute "__origin__"* by using `hasattr` / `getattr`. The following should work on Python 3.6+ in terms of both type checking and runtime behavior.

```py
from typing import Dict, List


def is_dict(cls: type) -> bool:
    if cls is dict:
        # Add this depending on whether you want to accept plain `dict`
        return True
    elif hasattr(cls, "__origin__"):
        origin = getattr(cls, "__origin__")
        # In Python 3.7+ origin will be `dict`, in Python 3.6 it is `Dict`
        return origin == dict or origin == Dict
    return False


assert not is_dict(int)
assert not is_dict(str)
assert not is_dict(List[int])
assert is_dict(dict)
assert is_dict(Dict[int, int])
```